# Kotlin variable getting initialized twice

Tags: android, kotlin

This is the function that gets the object in MyHttpsClient.java.

```
public static MyHttpsClient getClient(Context context, OnHttpsResult resultListener) throws Exception {
    Log.i("TAG","---------------------------" + context.getClass().getName() + " getClient!--------------------------------");
    for(String c : contextNames){
        if(c == context.getClass().getName()){
            throw new Exception("Can not be initialized twice in the same class");
        }
    }
    contextNames.add(context.getClass().getName());
    return new MyHttpsClient(context, resultListener);
}
```

I initialize it in Login.kt like this:

```
object MyHttpsListener : MyHttpsClient.OnHttpsResult{
    override fun OnResult(jsonObject: JSONObject?) {
        when(workid){
            0 -> {
                var status = jsonObject?.getInt("status")
                if(status == 1){
                    instance.startActivity(Intent(instance, MainActivity::class.java))
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(instance, "Incorrect email or password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                instance.pb_login.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }
}
var client = MyHttpsClient.getClient(this, MyHttpsListener)
```

After running app, I found that the "client" called 
 "getClient()" twice, so the app crashed.
Finally, I solved the problem in this way:

```
lateinit var client: MyHttpsClient
```

And the "client" initialized in onCreate

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    client = MyHttpsClient.getClient(this, MyHttpsListener)
    ...
}
```

But I don't know why this happened. I'm looking forward to someone who can help me.

Comment: I can not see an answer to your question in the code you provided. Probably you also initialized the login twice.

Comment: Sample is incomplete - where is declaration of `contextNames`? Is code from `Login.kt` in an activity or top level?

Comment: I would assume that `Context` is the `Activity`. But you don't have control over how often an activity class is created. And since you don't destroy `contextNames` with the `Activity`, you'll always run into these issues.

Comment: Yes, the 'Login.kt' is Activity, and it is also default Activity. Maybe it initialized by system twice. 
:)

Comment: Well, finally I found out what happened in my code. `private var instance : Login = Login()` I want to get the instence for `Login()`, but initialize it on the top and I didn't check it out. So sad.   :(

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a conection (`MyHttpsClient`) and you don't look to the connection you've already made, you can create multiple instance for the same conection and, in fact, for the same object.

The best way is to look for the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) which is a good patern to restrict number of conection and so the number of instance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah, the singleton pattern is the best way. But how I can impelementation the interface 'OnResult' and change the 'context' in 'MyHttpsClient' ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for taking the time to check my question. I am visited stackoverflow first time. Finally I found out my problem, I mistakenly initialized it at the top. And I will show the complete code next time..

```
private var instance : Login = Login()

class Login : AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
```